# How to set Marathi font to text view in android?

Tags: android

I am developing android application in Marathi language,
for that i want to set Marathi font to text view.
So please let me know how to set that

Thanking you..

Comment: The question is answered here for another language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052431/how-to-develop-a-complete-malayalam-app/25053518#25053518

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your font in assets folder, then create new Typeface from it

Here is an example

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "SomeFont.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all put your fonts in assests folder in your project.
then in textview in java file where you want to put marathi, use this code:

```
Typeface mfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "roboto_light.otf");
<your Textview>.setTypeface(mfont);
```

Answer (score 0):

Download marathi fonts and save it in assests folder and set typeface using that font.

Sample:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssests(), "name_of_font.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass unicode character like\u... to you textview text.

> > you can use converter to convert the language. Or can take a look http://www.unicodeonline.com/
> >     For getting the exact value you can pass your unicode into
> >     ResourceBundle.getBundle(unicodestoragelocation,locale).getString(UnicodeValue)