# Stroke in textview text android?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, styles, stroke

I need to style the text for textview as per the below image

[image: TEXT VIEW FONT]

The font being used is CARTER ONE font

This is my textview class

```
public class CustomTextViewCarter extends TextView {
private static Typeface mTypeface;
public CustomTextViewCarter(final Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomTextViewCarter(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);

}

public CustomTextViewCarter(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        if (mTypeface == null) {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getResources().getAssets(), "carter_one.ttf");
        }
        setTypeface(mTypeface);
    }
}
```

}

But the the same kind of text doesn't appear. How can it be done?

Comment: you can use **https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy** library

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for show custom TextView
**Step-1:**
**CustomTextView.java**

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "TextView";

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.CustomTV);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTV_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);  
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Step-2:** 
After that write below code in your **styles.xml** file

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTV">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

**Step-3:**
Use CustomTextView in your xml file 
Here com.app.demo is my package name.. use your package name instead of that,

```
<com.app.demo.CustomTextView
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="hello"
     android:textColor="@color/text"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     app:customFont="carter_one.ttf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
You can set ttf by making your own textview implementation.
It will works above API 15 (Ice cream sandwich).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5185587/850347

```
 <com.lht.ui.MyTextView
    android:text="Hello friends"
    lht:ttf_name="ITCBLKAD.TTF"
    />
```