# Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'typeface'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-support-library

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="TextViewAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="typeface">robotoRegular</item>            
    </style>

    <style name="TextViewAppearance.Display1" parent="@style/TextViewAppearance">
        <item name="typeface">robotoBlack</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">45sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_color_grey_500</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Getting Error:
**Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'typeface'.**

I'm using 
1. Android Studio 1.5.1 
2. minSdkVersion 15 
3. targetSdkVersion 23

<----------- Edit --------------------->

My Layout file is

```
<abcapp.com.font.RobotoTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
                android:text="ABC"               
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:typeface="robotoBlack" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The Typeface class specifies the typeface and intrinsic style of a
>   font.

You should call `android:typeface` instead of `typeface` .

**Don't**

```
<item name="typeface">robotoRegular</item>
```

**Do**

```
<item name="android:typeface">robotoRegular</item>
```

Comment: I'm using "app:typeface" in xml layout file. I have just added xml layout file code in my question

Comment: @smoke http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android

Answer (score 1):

you should use `android:typeface`,not `typeface`.

Comment: I'm using "app:typeface" in xml layout file. I have just added xml layout file code in my question

Comment: But looks like you didn't declare `app` tag like `android`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<item name="android:typeface">YOUR FONT</item>
```

Comment: I'm using "app:typeface" in xml layout file. I have just added xml layout file code in my question