# RecyclerView Custom Typeface Inside Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` to show three different text and I want to apply a custom `Typeface` to each one. Now in my adapter under `ViewHolder` I have put the `Typeface` code but not sure how to apply them to each `textView`.

Adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

List<AdapterData> mItems;

public Adapter() {
    super();
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    AdapterData data = new AdapterData();
    data.setTextOne("Title 1");
    data.setTextTwo("Title 2");
    data.setTextThree("Title 3");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setTextOne("Title 1");
    data.setTextTwo("Title 2");
    data.setTextThree("Title 3");

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setTextOne("Title 1");
    data.setTextTwo("Title 2");
    data.setTextThree("Title 3");
    mItems.add(data);


}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardview_items, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    AdapterData data = mItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.textOne.setText(data.getTextOne());
    viewHolder.textTwo.setText(data.getTextTwo());
    viewHolder.textThree.setText(data.getTextThree());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return mItems.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView textOne;
    public TextView textTwo;
    public TextView textThree;

    Typeface customTypeOne = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Typeface One.ttf");
    Typeface customTypeTwo = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Typeface Two.ttf");
    Typeface customTypeThree = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Typeface Three.ttf");


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textOne = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textTwo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textThree = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a custom typeface in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textOne;
        public TextView textTwo;
        public TextView textThree;

        Typeface customTypeOne = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Typeface One.ttf");
        Typeface customTypeTwo = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Typeface Two.ttf");
        Typeface customTypeThree = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Typeface Three.ttf");


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textOne = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textOne.setTypeface(customTypeOne);
            textTwo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textTwo.setTypeface(customTypeTwo);
            textThree = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            textThree.setTypeface(customTypeThree);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually just have to add the typefaces to the textview:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
...
textOne.setTypeface(customTypeOne)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTypeface() method to set the created typeface on yout textview:

```
textOne.setTypeface(customTypeOne);
textTwo.setTypeface(customTypeTwo);
textThree.setTypeface(customTypeThree);
```

I will also suggest you look into Calligraphy on github. It is a powerful library to handle typeface dilemma efficiently :)

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf");
viewHolder.textOne.setTypeface(myTypeface);
viewHolder.textOne.setText(data.getTextOne());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

List<AdapterData> mItems;

public Adapter() {
    super();
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    AdapterData data = new AdapterData();
    data.setTextOne("Title 1");
    data.setTextTwo("Title 2");
    data.setTextThree("Title 3");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setTextOne("Title 1");
    data.setTextTwo("Title 2");
    data.setTextThree("Title 3");

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setTextOne("Title 1");
    data.setTextTwo("Title 2");
    data.setTextThree("Title 3");
    mItems.add(data);


}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardview_items, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    AdapterData data = mItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.textOne.setText(data.getTextOne());
    viewHolder.textTwo.setText(data.getTextTwo());
    viewHolder.textThree.setText(data.getTextThree());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return mItems.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView textOne;
    public TextView textTwo;
    public TextView textThree;

    Typeface customTypeOne = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Typeface One.ttf");
    Typeface customTypeTwo = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Typeface Two.ttf");
    Typeface customTypeThree = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Typeface Three.ttf");


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textOne = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textTwo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textThree = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);


        textOne.setTypeface(customTypeOne);
        textTwo.setTypeface(customTypeTwo);
        textThree.setTypeface(customTypeThree);


    }
}
}
```