# How to enlarge the font size for whole application in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Now I developed native application in Android and I need to increase the font size of whole application using preferences how do I do that? Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Raj.

Comment: see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the font size for the entire project. But you can change the font size for each activity. Just check the below link. It will help you

[Is it possible to set font for entire Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application)

Answer (score -1):

You can't really do this. I think the least painful way would be to extend TextView plus whatever Views you want to use the new font size. Set your default font size there, then just use your custom TextView in all your layouts.