# Change the font of Custom dialog box title

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-fonts, android-typeface

Here's my code for the custom dialog box I've implemented

```
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("This is the Title");
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), 
            "fonts/Barkentina.otf"));
```

I'm easily able to change the font of the text inside dialogue box.  But what can I do to change the font of dialog title?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the font in your entire application then you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application/16883281#16883281).

As per your approach you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29162440/2014374) which uses `R.id.alertTitle` to find the alter dialog title id. Then you can set typeface to the TextView with the id.