# How to get the AlertDialog title?

Tags: android, testing, dialog

I tried to get the message and the following line of code works:

```
TextView dialogMessage = (TextView)dialogObject.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
```

But when I try to get the title using the following line it returns `null`

```
TextView dialogTitle = (TextView)dialogObject.findViewById(android.R.id.tittle);
```

Comment: the id is `alertTitle`, I am not sure it is visibile outside tough. Try with `android.R.id.alertTitle`

Comment: there is no id alertTitle

Answer (score 40):

I checked up the code of the `AlertDialog`. Internally they use `R.id.alertTitle` to initialize the `AlertDialog` title's `TextView`. You can use `getIdentifier` to retrieve it:

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier( "alertTitle", "id", "android" );
if (titleId > 0) {
   TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) dialogObject.findViewById(titleId);
   if (dialogTitle != null) {

   }
}
```

Edit: for `AppCompat`, the third argument of `getIdentifier` should be the package name of your app. You can retrieve the latter with `context.getPackageName()`

Comment: Despite the people saying not possible, this is great answer. you deserve the black belt, thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you happen to have similar android-fu to get the message :)

Comment: @DavidBerry Unfortunately I don't , but [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#message) is defined `android.R.id.message`. You could try using `message` instead of `"alertTitle"`. Sorry

Comment: Yep, just found it myself and indeed, it does work.  Thanks!

Comment: And the buttons appear to button1..n

Comment: For AppCompat AlertDialog you should use 
getResources().getIdentifier( "alertTitle", "id", "your.package.name" )

Comment: @Blackbelt answer should be extended with Sergei Belozerov note.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I always get null for the title TextView.

Comment: @doctorram answer is from 2015. It really depends what alert dialog you are importing. Back then there were no fancy alert dialogs like the ones from the support library.

Comment: @Blackbelt fancy or not, what's the solution now?  This solution no longer works.

Comment: @doctorram look at source code of the widget you are using.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the code from breaking, when Google decides to change its dialog title view id in the future, here is more reliable solution.

We will simply return the first encountered `View`, which its type is `TextView`.

```
//
// Usage: findFirstEncounteredType(getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView(), TextView.class)
//
public static View findFirstEncounteredType(View view, Class<? extends View> klass) {
    if (klass.isInstance(view)) {
        return view;
    } else {
        if (!(view instanceof ViewGroup)) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;

    for (int i=0, ei=viewGroup.getChildCount(); i<ei; i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        View result = findFirstEncounteredType(child, klass);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Should be top rated answear

Comment: There is no TextView found at all!

Comment: I was not finding any TextView until I did the search after calling dialog.show()

Answer (score 2):

I know the question mentions AlertDialog, but if you came here through a Google search and looking for the answer for a `DialogFragment`:

```
getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.title))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it your self. Create your own class that extend android.app.AlertDialog.Builder. And then create a variable to store your value after using the method setTitle().

---

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.StringRes;

public class AlertDialog extends android.app.AlertDialog.Builder {

    private Context context;
    private String title;

    public AlertDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public AlertDialog(Context context, int themeResId) {
        super(context, themeResId);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Set title using string
     */
    @Override
    public AlertDialog setTitle(CharSequence title) {

        // set the title
        this.title = title.toString();

        super.setTitle(title);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Set title using resource string
     */
    @Override
    public AlertDialog setTitle(@StringRes int titleId) {

        this.title = this.context.getText(titleId).toString();

        super.setTitle(titleId);
        return this;
    }

    // create public method
    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

And then use you can use it as ordinary AlertDialog, with implemented method which get its title. Then you can test it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Crete new alert dialog
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Type some message here :D");
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.settings_title);           // string resource
        dialog.setTitle("Dialog1 title");                   // string
        dialog.show();

        // Crete secondary dialog with same title
        // using getTitle() method
        new AlertDialog(this)
                .setTitle(dialog.getTitle())
                .setMessage("Copy title from first dialog.")
                .show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old post but I used the accepted answer and added something else useful to me. You can make the Dialog title multiline (default 1 line) using the code below. I also read out the preset title because I added txt asynchronously later on using ContentLoaders

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier( "alertTitle", "id", "android" );
        if (titleId > 0) {
            TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) getDialog().findViewById(titleId);
            if (dialogTitle != null) {
                dialogTitle.setMaxLines(4);
                dialogTitle.setSingleLine(false);
                String txt = dialogTitle.getText().toString();
                String txt1 = txt + ":\n\n" + "next line txt";
                dialogTitle.setText(txt1);
            }
        }
```