# Displaying foreign language characters in Android Java

Tags: java, android, html, xml, unicode

This is probably weird question, but I am trying to display Geez alphabets on an android app. Geez alphabets are used in Eritrea and Ethiopia. The unicode ranges from U+1200 and U+137F (decimal 4608–4991). More info can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge'ez_script#Unicode

Currently, I have just added the characters directly to the name in strings.xml like:

[image]

But it's not displaying it when I run the App on other devices device. it works good on my Galaxy S4 because Geez alohabets are already included in this device by default.

How do I display such characters on devices that don't support it by defauly, if possible?

Btw, the xml is using utf-8 encoding

Comment: @bstar55 - That's not relevant.  He wants to know how to deal with missing fonts.

Comment: @henok - If the phone ROM doesn't have your font, you'll have to add it in yourself as thinzar00 pointed out. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application

Answer (score 1):

This is how I include Myanmar unicode fonts inside my apps, not sure it will be relevant to you.

1. save a copy of font file (TTF) under assets/font
2. extends the TextView to set the default typeface (In your case maybe EditText)

   private void init() {
       if (!isInEditMode()) {
           Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                       "fonts/fontfile.ttf");
           setTypeface(tf);
       
   }

   }

Comment: Thanks for your time, but that's not what I'm trying to do.