# Use custom font in style attribute

Tags: android, fonts, xamarin

What I want to achieve is adding `style` attribute to my `axml` file with custom font loaded from `Asset`.

I know I can load built-in fontface like this (`style.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And use it (`Main.axml`):

```
<TextView
        style="@style/CodeFont"
        local:MvxBind="Text Hello" />
```

I know that I can also create `MyCustomTextView` extending `TextView` and setting font by `SetTypeface` method, but I would like to use custom font in `style` attribute.

So something like:

```
 <resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
      <item name="android:typeface">MyCustomFontLoadedFromAsset</item>
    </style>
 </resources>
```

Is it possible (and how to do it)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a way to do it straight out of the box. There's a library called [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) that will let you do it. It will work on API 7+

I've also seen a trick using reflection to override serif/sans so that you can define those in your `styles.xml`: [Is it possible to set a custom font for entire of application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application), though I would recommend the first approach.

Comment: It supports API7+, Only the example is API16 :)

Comment: Thanks @Chris.Jenkins , I guess, as the author, you'd know! I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Ben Pearson How to Apply it for whole Application? Hop You will reply me fast!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but nowadays you can do exactly that with the `fontFamily` attribute ([see the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#adding-fonts-to-style)):

```
<style name="customfontstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/yourcustomfont</item>
</style>
```

Obviously you need to have previously defined that `fontFamily`. To do so, please see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#font-family).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/yourcustomfont_regular" />
    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/yourcustomfont_italic" />
</font-family>
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Typeface normalFont;
    private Typeface boldFont;

    ...

    /**
     * Fonts
     */
    public void setTypeface(TextView textView) {
        if(textView != null) {
            if(textView.getTypeface() != null && textView.getTypeface().isBold()) {
                textView.setTypeface(getBoldFont());
            } else {
                textView.setTypeface(getNormalFont());
            }
        }
    }

    private Typeface getNormalFont() {
        if(normalFont == null) {
            normalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/my_font.ttf");
        }
        return this.normalFont;
    }

    private Typeface getBoldFont() {
        if(boldFont == null) {
            boldFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/my_font_bold.ttf");
        }
        return this.boldFont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that we have to do a check for bold (or italic) text styles, the code is going to be a little longer. Since we don't want to repeat this code throughout each Activity or Fragment that applies our custom font, I prefer to put the code in the Application class.

Comment: Downvote, as this does not answer the question. This answer only repeats what has already been done by the OP.

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.

Answer (score -3):

```
String fontPath = "PT_Sans-Narrow-Web-Regular.ttf";

holder.desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msgdesc);
// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(
        row.getContext().getAssets(), fontPath);

// Applying font
holder.desc.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Downvote, as this does not answer the question. This answer only repeats what has already been done by the OP.

Answer (score -4):

```
info1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
            "fonts/KeepCalm-Medium.ttf");
info1.setTypeface(font);
info1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: You can use this method to Add Custom Font from assets. First we download any font for example  KeepCalm-Medium.ttf then the font willl be save in assets folder u can easly solve the problem

Comment: Downvote, as this does not answer the question. This answer only repeats what has already been done by the OP.