# Custom fonts in Android API below 16?

Tags: android, fonts

Im working on my first Android application bigger than one activity.

I've read this:

> Android 4.1 adds several more variants of the Roboto font style for a
>   total of 10 variants, and they're all usable by apps. Your apps now
>   have access to the full set of both light and condensed variants.

(here: [link](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html))

I also read somewhere, that I can use custom TTF font.

**Does it mean, that Android API below 4.1 (API 16) cannot support custom fonts?**

Do I have to work on API 16 or above? I have 4.0.4 phone for now, I don't want to throw it away yet...

Answer (score 4):

Don't throw away your phone! You certainly can use custom fonts below API level 16.

First add your font (ttf file) to your `/assets` folder, then do something like:

```
Typeface typeface  = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)

It has been around since API level 1.

The fonts in your question can be used without having to include any font file - they are not "custom" but built into the platform and available for all to use.

Comment: Well, it's a bit painful to do that for all TextView and other objects. I guess there is no way to apply font to whole activity... I am right? Im worried about activity initialization performance impact when I do some for loop that does that for all objects.

Comment: You could try this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application/16883281#16883281 I have done it the above way and it was not too painful. Just reuse your Typeface object.