# TextView isBold always returns NORMAL

Tags: android, fonts, textview, styles, typeface

I am setting Typeface of a textview like this

```
textView.setTypeface(tf_roboto_medium, Typeface.BOLD);
```

When I check the style using this command, it is evaluated true.

```
if (textView.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.NORMAL) {
// always here
}
else {
// never here
}
```

[EDIT] Here is my xml content for the TextView

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Train"
                android:textColor="#777777"
                android:gravity="bottom|center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/txt_train"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:textSize="32px"
                android:onClick="onTrainClick"
                android:clickable="true" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS : I have read other posts asking for the same thing. None of them seems to work for me. Thus the quesiton

Answer (score -1):

Try one of these this:

1. `if (textView.getTypeface().isBold()) {`
2. `if ((textView.getTypeface().getStyle() & Typeface.BOLD) > 0) {`

From what I see there is a bit mask used for font styles. Normal == 0 so there can be problems with 0 & 0

Comment: 1. isBold() - same behavior. says "not bold" always.
2. this is compilation error.

Comment: yeap I forgot about > 0 :) It still shouldn't make a difference because it's the implementation of isBold(). I don't have more ideas, maybe there is something wrong about the font...

Comment: Thanks Mark for the comment. I tried everything that was available in stackoverflow questions. Nothing seem to work. I will disable the font and check once.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a string:

```
<string name="train"><b>Train</b></string>
```

And then set:

```
android:text="@string/train"
```