# How to change font family of Textview in whole application?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, fonts, textview

I want to change `font-family` of `textview` in whole app

Currently I'm using below code

i have added `font` inside my `res/font` folder ([Click here to check res/font directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5zh7.png))

Here is my `font.xml` files

> font/font_one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        android:font="@font/oswald_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/oswald_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

    <font
        android:font="@font/oswald_bold"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/oswald_bold"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

</font-family>
```

> @font/font_two

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        android:font="@font/opensans_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/opensans_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/opensans_bold"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/opensans_bold"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

</font-family>
```

> here is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sampleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?backColor"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font_two"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="?textColor"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sampleTextView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?backColor"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font_one"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="?textColor"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/fontSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/themeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChaneFont"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:text="Change Font"
        android:textColor="?textColor" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChaneTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:text="Change Theme"
        android:textColor="?textColor" />


</LinearLayout>
```

> here is my output when i'm using **`android:fontFamily`** its woking fine as per my requirement

[**OUTPUT using `android:fontFamily="@font/font_one"` from XML**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg9Yg.png)

[**OUTPUT using `android:fontFamily="@font/font_two"` from XML**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40mV1.png)

> here is the code of my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner fontSpinner, themeSpinner;

    Button btnChaneFont, btnChaneTheme;

    TextView sampleTextView, sampleTextView2;

    int theme = R.style.AppTheme;

    String[] fontsArray = new String[]{"Oswald Fonts", "Open Sans Fonts", "Raleway Fonts"};
    String[] themeArray = new String[]{"Theme 1", "Theme 2", "Theme 3"};

    Typeface typeface = null;

    PrefManager prefManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new ThemeColors(this);

        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        getTheme().applyStyle(prefManager.getTheme(), true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        fontSpinner = findViewById(R.id.fontSpinner);
        themeSpinner = findViewById(R.id.themeSpinner);

        btnChaneFont = findViewById(R.id.btnChaneFont);
        btnChaneTheme = findViewById(R.id.btnChaneTheme);

        btnChaneFont.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnChaneTheme.setOnClickListener(this);

        fontSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        themeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        sampleTextView = findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView);
        sampleTextView2 = findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> fontAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, fontsArray);
        fontSpinner.setAdapter(fontAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> themeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, themeArray);
        themeSpinner.setAdapter(themeAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == btnChaneTheme) {
            recreate();
        }

        if (view == btnChaneFont) {

            sampleTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
            sampleTextView2.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {

        switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.fontSpinner:
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(MainActivity.this, R.font.font_one);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(MainActivity.this, R.font.font_two);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(MainActivity.this, R.font.font_three);
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case R.id.themeSpinner:
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        prefManager.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        prefManager.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        prefManager.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme3);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Now when i'm changing the typeface of text view progrmatically using java I'm getting below result

[OUTPUT using font/font_two" from JAVA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdrAg.png)

[OUTPUT using font/font_two" from JAVA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Ayf.png)

> Currently i'm facing below issue using above code

- When i'm setting `font-family` using `XML` i'm getting both font effect **normal** and **italic** but when i'm setting `font-family` using `java` the **italic** font doesn't setting correctly (you can check the result of both i have added the screenshot)
- how can set `font-family` using `java`
- is there any way to set for whole application
- How can  get the  same behaviour of `font-family` as `XML`  using `java`

Can any body help me on this i want to change `font-family` of whole app

> here are some other post that i have visited but didn't help me to solve my problem

- [How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android/54482273#54482273)
- [Valid values for android:fontFamily and what they map to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to)
- [Android - set TextView TextStyle programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919173/android-set-textview-textstyle-programmatically)
- [Set TextView style (bold or italic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/set-textview-style-bold-or-italic)
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml
- [set font at runtime, Textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483110/set-font-at-runtime-textview)
- [Changing all typefaces of an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218795/changing-all-typefaces-of-an-android-application/31219701#31219701)

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44363010/4762767

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called Calligraphy
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Or create a custom TextView and set font at constructor
In this way you should replace all the TextView in your xmls to CustomFontTextView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomFontTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setCustomFont();
    }

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont();
    }

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont();
    }

    private void setCustomFont() {
        setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
    }

}
```

> Typeface.create()

it's not safe approach to get a font.

Look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16902532/10995239

Comment: Thanks for the answer  i know i can use `Calligraphy` lib but i want solution without using any lib