# Why my custom font is not being applied to all my application?

Tags: android

Is it possible to set a custom font in an Android application?

I tried what is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16883281/760893), but I don't know where my `extends Application` class is...

Any help?

**EDIT:**

I tried the following:

- Add an assets folder and insert the font inside as seen here:

[image]

- Add a new class that extends from `Application`
- Call this new class from my `AndroidManifest.xml`.
- I went to my style and added it.

**MyApp.java:**

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "raleway_regular.ttf");
    //  This FontsOverride comes from the example I posted above
  }
  }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:name=".MyApp"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     ....
```

**styles.xml:**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">default</item>
 </style>
```

But my font is still not changning... any idea?

Then the `MyApp` class is called. But no effect on my fonts...

**EDIT2:** I realized that my buttons apply the custom font after I set a custom style for my buttons. Here is my custom button style:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

And here is how it looks now:

[image]

So: my button is applying the style, but not the `TextView`. Any idea on why my custom font is not being applied for all items in application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. But you need to initialize your TextView or Button in code by `findViewByIdMethod(int id)`.

```
TextView yourTextView = findViewById(R.id.YourTextViewId);    
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"raleway_regular.ttf");
yourTextView.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: I know there are ways to do it one by one... and this works fine one by one. But I would like to make it generally...

Answer (score 1):

there is a grate library for custom fonts in android:[custom fonts](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

here is a sample how to use it.

in gradle you need to put this line

```
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
```

and then make a class that extends application an write this code `public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

```
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                    .setDefaultFontPath("your font path")
                    .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                    .build()
    );
}
```

}`

and in the activity class put this method before onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
```

and the last thing in your manifest file write like this.

```
 <application
    android:name=".App"
```

and it will change the whole activity to your font! its simple and clean!

Comment: I'm not looking for an android font... Acutally I have to use the "Raleway" font...

Comment: its not a font its to change your fonts and you can add any font you want and it will appear every where if you want i can post the code how i used it

Comment: Oh, that's a custom library! :O I have to give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set font for entire application, just follow this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/8854794/3718505 .

But it works only for static content.

Comment: What do you mean with static content?

Comment: If you not going to change text.