# How to change default font of the android app?

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, android-typeface

I want to make an app in a non English language. So I need the textviews, strings and the toast to be in the non-English language. Setting the typeface for every text is cumbersome. Is there a way to set a default font? When I have to refer to something in English (like email id) then I can use the textview.settypeface(xyz) method.

Comment: you can try this link https://coderwall.com/p/qxxmaa/android-use-a-custom-font-everywhere

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a grate library for custom fonts in android: [custom fonts](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

Here is a sample how to use it.

In gradle you need to put this line:

```
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
```

Then make a class that extends application and write this code:

```
public class App extends Application { 
@Override public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();

CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("your font path")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build()
);
}
}
```

In the activity class put this method before onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

In your manifest file write like this:

```
<application
android:name=".App"
```

It will change the whole activity to your font!. I'ts simple solution and clean!

Comment: Here's a video of the guy who made the library explaining how it works  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZkZVCWxIXs

Comment: I did the above steps. Default font is replaced successfully, but bold, italic, etc styles are not applied to the new font on device.

Comment: @Mishty try to get a bold, italics font version of the same font. And use setTypeface() and use these fonts

Comment: Is there a calligraphy project for eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in mainly 3 ways. one way would be to create a custom TextView and refer that everywhere,  ie :

```
    public class TypefacedTextView extends TextView {

    public TypefacedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontName);
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```

and inside View.xml

```
<packagename.TypefacedTextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Hello"/>
```

Another way, is to use the powerful `Calligraphy` library in github. [see this](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

And finally, you can override the defaults with your own fonts, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application)