# set textView font and typeface from xml instead of using java

Tags: android, xml, android-assets, android-fonts

In xml code i can use fontfamily like below :

```
<TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:fontFamily="monospace"
       android:typeface="monospace"
                                  />
```

and i can set type face in my acivity as below :

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(typeface);
```

is there any way to set font in xml from Assets() folder to set custom typeFace?

i want to reach some thing like this...

```
<TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:typeface="@assets/font.ttf"
/>
```

i searched for some thing like that, but i didn't find useful soulution.

Comment: [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-a-custom-font-for-entire-of-application Tri this

Comment: You can create your own `TextView` and apply your desire font style

Comment: @MD  thanks, but if there custom way for android instead of library it will be better.

Comment: on android o its possible you can define a font family also. Calligraphy for other versions

Comment: @IbrahimAli one more [Custom fonts](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/custom-fonts-on-android-dynamic-font-selection-via-xml)

Comment: @IbrahimAli check my answer and let me know.

Comment: @ArpitPatel i will

Answer (score 0):

after launching o , You will define your custom font like this:

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
</font-family>
```

In XmlFile Look Like This:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1 :**

Create **assets** folder and in this folder create another folder **fonts**  see below image. After creating these folders paste your ttf files in fonts folder.

[image]

**STEP 2 :** Create **attrs.xml** file in values folder see below image and paste this code.

[image]

**CODE**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
        <attr name="font" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**STEP 3 :**

Create **CustomTextview.class** and paste this code

```
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);

    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);

            String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_font);

            try {
                if (fontName != null) {
                    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
                    setTypeface(myTypeface);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            a.recycle();
        }
    }

}
```

**STEP 4 :**

Declare your customTextview in xml file like below.

Use this attribute `app:font="your ttf file"`

**Note ->**   `com.javacodegeeks.androidcustomfontexample.CustomTextView` indicate that your package name and class name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <com.javacodegeeks.androidcustomfontexample.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="This is a custom text view!"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:font="arial.ttf" />

</LinearLayout>
```

YOU CAN GRAB DEMO FROM [HERE](https://github.com/arpit999bicubic/AndroidCustomFontExample)

I hope it help