# Use fonts from support library in Leanback

Tags: android-support-library, android-tv

From android support library 26 onwards, it is possible to use [fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html#using-support-lib) in styles and widgets. You then have to use `AppCompatActivity` and use styles extending from `Theme.AppCompat`.

I would like to use custom fonts in Android TV (using the support library), but then I cannot use the `Theme.Leanback` style.

Is there a way of using the `Theme.Leanback` style with the font support?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-a-custom-font-for-entire-of-application

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate of that. I know how to use fonts (and the many alternatives like custom widgets, calligraphy, databinding, programmatically, etc). 

My question is not about using fonts in general, but specific to the support libarary and the leanback theme.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

build.gradle:

`implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'`

Example of applying a font in `assets/font/fancyfont.otf` it to a `GuidedStepFragment activity:

LoginActivity.kt:

```
class LoginActivity : Activity() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase))
    }
}
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="LoginActivityTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback.GuidedStep">
    <item name="guidanceTitleStyle">@style/Login.TitleStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Login.TitleStyle" parent="Widget.Leanback.GuidanceTitleStyle">
    <item name="fontPath">font/fancy_font.otf</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/LoginActivityTheme"/>
```